# Won't the secondary condensate p trap evaporate?

Tags: hvac, air-conditioning, heat-pump, central-air

So my understanding is that both the primary and secondary condensate drain lines should have p traps installed to prevent air ingress (or egress depending of it's a positive or negative air system).

However, during normal operation, the secondary condensate drain line should never see water, so over the summer, isn't it likely for the water in the secondary condensate drain line to evaporate?  How would that trap ever get refilled?

Comment: Lot of these primary drains do not have traps at all.  Mine does not. It is a route for air to bypass the coil in the cooling mode and for heated air (N gas furnace) to escape. Maybe a trap is part of a high efficiency unit but our 17 SEER doesn't justify it.

Comment: Yes, I have a high efficiency unit

Comment: Also there are some a/c units retrofitted to houses which were originally without ductwork. The rettrofit ducts are smaller in cross sectional area and the air  in the ducts has a high linear flow. This is accomplished by higher pressure at the outlet of the air handler. In those units the condensate trap may be more important.

Comment: Also there are some a/c units retrofitted to houses which were originally without ductwork. The retrofit ducts are smaller in cross sectional area and the air  in the ducts has a high linear flow. This is accomplished by higher pressure at the outlet of the air handler. In those units the condensate trap may be more important.